# XML сериализация определенной схемы

Tags: c#, xml

коллеги.
Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли стандартным методом System.Xml.Serialization сериализовать из объекта подобный xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<s n="EnquiryRequest">
    <a n="accountClass">1</a>
    <a n="reason">02</a>
    <c n="Consumer">
        <s>
            <a n="applicantType">01</a> 
            <a n="sex">1</a>
            <c n="Address">
                <s>
                    <a n="addressType">1</a>
                    <a n="addressFlag">1</a>
                </s>
            </c>
        </s>
    </c>
</s>
```

Если можно, то как организовать классы.
Или собирать xml хардкодом?
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно, только здесь, очевидно не один объект, а 11 объектов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Студия подсказывает такую организацию классов (Правка-Специальная вставка-Вставить XML как классы):

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class s
    {

        private sA[] aField;

        private sC cField;

        private string nField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("a")]
        public sA[] a
        {
            get
            {
                return this.aField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.aField = value;
            }
        }

        public sC c
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string n
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class sA
    {

        private string nField;

        private byte valueField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string n
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public byte Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class sC
    {

        private sCS sField;

        private string nField;

        public sCS s
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string n
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class sCS
    {

        private sCSA[] aField;

        private sCSC cField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("a")]
        public sCSA[] a
        {
            get
            {
                return this.aField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.aField = value;
            }
        }

        public sCSC c
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class sCSA
    {

        private string nField;

        private byte valueField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string n
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public byte Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class sCSC
    {

        private sCSCA[] sField;

        private string nField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("a", IsNullable = false)]
        public sCSCA[] s
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string n
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class sCSCA
    {

        private string nField;

        private byte valueField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string n
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public byte Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все получилось.